# Comparing column in same file to insert one more column to the same file

Tags: shell, awk

I have one need to compare specific columns (column 3 and 6) and where both numbers are defined, add the ratio of column 3 to column 6 as an extra column 7.

My File

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 
a    s318  14   -    -     -
b    s319  25   b   t568   15    
c    s320  8    c   t569   12   
-    -     -    d   t570   20      
f    s322  42   f   t571    5
```

Expected output

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 ratio
a    s318  14   -    -     -     0
b    s319  25   b   t568   15    1.67
c    s320  8    c   t569   12    0.67
-    -     -    d   t570   20    0
f    s322  42   f   t571    5    8.4
```

I used an `awk` script to get the result but it's showing `awk: (FILENAME=file.txt FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted`.

```
awk 'NR==1{$7="ratio"}NR>1{if($3!=$6)print $7=($3)/($6)}{print}' file.txt
```

I need help; can you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ternary operator to check if the  value of column 6 is positive:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{$7="ratio"}NR>1{ $7=$6>0?$3/$6:0}{print}' OFS='\t' file 
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 ratio
a    s318 14   -    -    -    0
b    s319 25   b    t568 15   1.66667
c    s320 8    c    t569 12   0.666667
-    -    -    d    t570 20   0
f    s322 42   f    t571 5    8.4
```